# Can we please split this question?

Tags: discussion

This question violates the SE principle of *one question per question* already in the title:

[2 questions about "Cast Away"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/2-questions-about-cast-away)

I flagged it for mod attention, without any result. Can we please do something about this?

This not only is a horrible ungoogleable title and has the problem that you don't know which answer is the best, it also sets a terrible example for future questions.

I have no idea why this bugs me so much. Maybe because I think that we don't have that much content anyway, we should at least keep the content we have organised.

I see two ways to solve this:

- Split the question via mod tools somehow. (if possible)
- Ask the user to open another question for his second question (we did this), if he does not want to, delete one of both.

SE is about quality before quantity. The fact that both questions already have answers should not prevent us from cleaning this up. Of course the content should be preserved if possible. But see [this discussion on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted) for example, where it seems to be consensus that the fact that something might be helpful now does not mean that it can violate SE rules.

Answer (score 1):

I received the flag, but there are no mod tools to split a question.  I left a comment for the person asking the question, with no response.

The only course of action open to me is edit to delete the second question, and encourage the user to ask it separately.

It annoys me a little, but mainly because the OP clearly isn't bothered to respond to our comments, or look at the answers.

Comment: This has the problem, though, that the 2nd question is actually the much better one, not being speculative plot-hole rubbish. And the OP is very likely to not care for reasking it if edited out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposition:

- Delete question #2 (Q2) from the question (Q1).
- Reopen Q2 and transform it to Community Wiki (the OP clearly does not seem to care about the rep anyway). This should be possible according to: ["Questions no longer have the option of being community wiki unless switched over by a moderator"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71085/155177) (i.e. Mods can create CW questions)
- Give people some time to move their answers from Q1 to Q2.
- Edit out old answer parts on Q1 if necessary. If important answers are missing on the new question, repost them as Community Wiki on Q2 as well.

This will ensure that no content is lost, but we still have two proper questions with respective answers.

Comment: Ok, i'll leave it a bit to see whether anyone sees a problem with this, then I'll do it.